# How to change templates using angular

Tags: angularjs

I have just started to learn angular.

I have the following:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/', {
                    controller: 'RouteCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'views/partials/index.html'
                }).
                when('/about', {

                    templateUrl: 'views/partials/about.html'
                }).
                when('/contact', {

                    templateUrl: 'views/partials/contact.html'
                }).
                when('/login', {
                    templateUrl:  'themes/admin/views/admin/partials/login.html'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    templateUrl: 'views/partials/index.html',
                    controller: function ($scope) {
                        $scope.message = 'Welcome!!';
                      }
                });
        }
    ]);
```

The login should have a completly different layout as from the other views.
In yii I would just put something like `$this->layout = admin-column1;`

How do I switch in angular from layout as I have 2 different types of layouts, one from my website and one admin cms layout?

The problem is that the ng-view use the same `<head></head>` and footer includes, I want to change that dynamically.

Comment: How does your main html page look like? From this little information you provided I would expect the template you provide in otherwise to be the main page which hosts one `ng-view` where you can define whatever template you need based on route

Comment: True but i am trying to achieve is make a link like the following: i want to link to a controller <li ><a href="/site/login">Login</a></li> and load a new theme, is that possible?

Comment: because when i do this the url changes to site/login# and the view is not found

Comment: The view is not found most likely because it can't resolve the template by 'themes/admin/views/admin/partials/login.html'. `site/login#` is what should be in an angular application, it means angular compiled successfully

Comment: Well quick fix what i did since angular doesnot let me change my head completely. I put <li onclick='$("body").html("");location.reload(true);'><a href="/login">Login</a></li> In order to refresh my page, this way the request is first send to my normal yii controller in which i can set the layout i want and from there angular takes over.